# golang gorp insert multiple records

Tags: go, gorp

Using gorp how can one insert multiple records efficiently? i.e instead of inserting one at a time, is there a batch insert?

```
var User struct {
   Name string
   Email string
   Phone string
}
var users []Users
users = buildUsers()
dbMap.Insert(users...) //this fails compilation
//I am forced to loop over users and insert one user at a time. Error Handling omitted for brevity
```

Is there a better mechanism with gorp? Driver is MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

As I found out on some other resource the reason this doesn't work is that `interface{}` and `User{}` do not have the same layout in memory, therefore their slices aren't of compatible types. Suggested solution was to convert `[]User{}` into `[]interface{}` in for loop, like shown here: https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

There is still on caveat: you need to use pointers for `DbMap.Insert()`function.

Here's how I solved it:

```
s := make([]interface{}, len(users))
for i, v := range users {
    s[i] = &v
}
err := dbMap.Insert(s...)
```

**Note** that `&v` is important, otherwise `Insert` will complain about non-pointers.

Comment: This is the best answer for multiple batch insert using gorp. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like gorp has anything that gives a wrapper for either raw SQL or multi value inserts (which is always SQL dialect dependent).
Are you worried about speed or transactions?  If not, I would just do the inserts in a for loop.